# Django form wizard - Indentation error in done() method?

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to write my done() method but I am getting an Indenation error:

```
IndentationError at /addWizard/
expected an indented block (views.py, line 105)
```

My views.py (Line 105 is the if statement)

```
class AddWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return ['business/add_{0}_form.html'.format(self.steps.current)]

    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        if form_list[0].get('ad_type') == '1': #LINE 105
            ad_type = "Basic"
        else:
            ad_type = "Other"

        return render_to_response('business/done.html', {
            'form_data': ad_type,
        })
```

The only way it works if it that return statement is by itself. I have been staring at it for hours.

Comment: the if statement in the done() method

Comment: Do you have a mixture of tabs and spaces? If so that is almost certainly your problem.

Comment: @PeterRowell: Yes, I also think this is the no. 1 suspect. The code on SO does not show the tabs, though.

Comment: @Tadeck: I don't think it's a matter of not showing tabs, I don't think it's possible to type a TAB at all. When you hit TAB you are advanced to the next form field. Also, if you are doing a copy-paste the tab character is often converted to spaces, thereby hiding the evidence.

Comment: Yeap... Mix of tabs and spaces was the problem... Thanks everyone!